# Why the incoming string is different when print it out more than twice?

Tags: c++

```
int deleteFile(const char* filePath)
{
    int rc;
    int retVal ;

    logPrint("filePath=%s \n",filePath);  
    logPrint("call delete file,  filePath=%s \n",filePath);

    if( (rc=FileHelper::DeleteFile(filePath)) == true &&
        FileHelper::FileExists(filePath) == false)
    {
          logPrint(" file deleted successfully \n");    
          retVal = 1;   
    }
    else
    {
         logPrint(" file deleted failed \n");       
         retVal = -1;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

The first `logPrint("filePath=%s \n",filePath);`

printed out :

> `"\mnt\app\datafile.db"`

However, the second `logPrint("call delete file,  filePath=%s \n",filePath);`

printed out :

> `"call delete file, call delete file"`

So it seems the filePath is changed. How it gets changed before deleteFile() returns?

Comment: `FileHelper::DeleteFile` how is it `C`?

Comment: Probably your `logPrint` is doing something *bad*.

Comment: Haven't cracked open your debugger and stepped through your code yet?

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is that you are passing in a string that has already been deleted. The first call using it succeeds because that memory hasn't been cleaned/re-used, but the second call shows you the randaom garbage because after the call to `logPrint()`, that memory area has been reused. The second (and less likely) possibility that occurs to me is that your `logPrint()` function is doing naughty things to the passed in string.

Comment: What happened to the `filePath=` that is supposed to be in your output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the caller function used a buffer that is not belong to it to store the "filePath" and pass the pointer to your function. The buffer apparently used by the log print function in your case. Here is one example that caller's behavior:

```
     const char* getFilePath(){
           const char* p= "\mnt\app\datafile.db";      
           return p;
     }

     void caller_function(){
           int ret;
           const char * path = getFilePath();    
           ret =  deleteFile(path);
           if(ret != 1)
               printf("delete File failed ");
           return;
     }
```

getFilePath() used a local buffer (char * p) to saved the file path, and pass this local buffer pointer p to caller_function(). After getFilePath() is returned, the local buffer memory is released from stack. The buffer is free to be used by any functions. 
C use a lot passing by reference, as programmer, you have to be very careful and making sure the reference buffer is not destroyed when the function is done.

One way to fix the problem is using a static buffer to store the file path, "static const" variables are created once and aren't destroyed when the function exits.

```
      const char* getFilePath(){
           static const char* p= "\mnt\app\datafile.db";      
           return p;
      }
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the problem. I am thinking to use malloca to reserve a memory to store the filepath. Not sure which way is better between malloca and static const.

Comment: using malloca() is also fine, just remember to free the memory once you are done with the file path, otherwise it will cause memory leak.